# Two indistinguishable stochastic processes are equivalent

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have the following definitions.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probabilised space.
Let's take two stochastic processes $(X(t))_{i\in I}$ and $(Y(t))_{i\in I}$ with values in a separable Banach space $E$ endowed with its borelian sigma-algebra $\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{B}(E)$, where $I$ is an arbitrary set of indices.

- $Y$ is a *modification* of $X$ if for all $t\in I$, $\mathbb{P}(X(t)=Y(t))=1$.
- $X$ and $Y$ are equivalent if for all $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, for all $(t_1,\dots,t_n)\in I^n$, the random variables $(X(t_1),\dots,X(t_n))$ and $(Y(t_1),\dots,Y(t_n))$ with values in $E^n$ follow the same distribution.
- $Y$ and $Y$ are indistinguishable if there exists $\Omega_0\subset\Omega$ with $\mathbb{P}(\Omega_0)=1$ such that for all $\omega\in\Omega_0$, for all $t\in I$, $X(t)=Y(t)$, or equivalently $\mathbb{P}(\sup\limits_{t\in I}\vert X(t)-Y(t)\vert>0)=0$.

I have shown that if two stochastic processes are indistinguishable, then they are modification of each other. But I am not able to prove that if they are modification of each other, then they must be equivalent.

From the definition, I can only consider the different probabilies for each $t_1,\dots,t_n$,but how do I assemble this to make sure that the laws are the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\bigcap_i \{X(t_i)=Y(t_i)\}$ Then $P(A)=1$ and $(X_{t_1},X_{t_2},\dots,X_{t_n})=(Y_{t_1},Y_{t_2},\dots,Y_{t_n})$ on $A$. Hence $P((X_{t_1},X_{t_2},\dots,X_{t_n}) \in C)=P((Y_{t_1},Y_{t_2},\dots,Y_{t_n}) \in C)$ for any Borel set $C$ in $ E^{n}$.

Comment: Hi Kavi, thanks for the answer.
Shouldn't it be any borel set in $E^n$ ?

Comment: @Flewer47 Thanks. Answer corrected.

Comment: Why is $\mathbb{P}(A)=1$ ? It is an uncountable intersection of sets, each being of probability 1, but the fact that it is uncountable is a bit problematic, isn't it ?

Comment: It is a **finite** intersection.

Comment: Indeed, you consider $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, times $t_1,\dots,t_n$ and then do your calculations. Got it, thanks !